# No Such Column SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Does anyone know why I get the error that I "do not have" a column named COL2?

```
Error inserting COL2=sdfsdf
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table TWhereToGoList has no column named COL2 (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO TWhereToGoList(COL2) VALUES (?)
```

My Contract class here I create the DB variables:

```
public static final class YourEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "TWhereToGoList";
    public static final String intWhereToGoListOID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL2 = "COL2";
```

I would like to ask you if you could help me out there:

My DB Helper class (snippets):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.deleteDatabase(new File(DATABASE_NAME));
    String createTable = ("CREATE TABLE " + Contract.YourEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            Contract.YourEntry.intWhereToGoListOID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            Contract.YourEntry.COL2 + "TEXT);"
    );
    db.execSQL(createTable);

public boolean addData(String string) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //Wo dass die values hingelegt werden @COL2
    values.put(Contract.YourEntry.COL2, string);
```

I get the error right here:

> ```
>     long result = db.insert(Contract.YourEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
> ```

```
    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any answers, if you have some questions ask in the comments below :)

Comment: add space after TEXT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you are missing a white space at your database creation:

```
String createTable = ("CREATE TABLE " + Contract.YourEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        Contract.YourEntry.intWhereToGoListOID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        Contract.YourEntry.COL2 + " TEXT);"
);
```

in the last part, you should have an extra space `" TEXT);"` which is now  `"TEXT);"`

Comment: Thanks, nice it works! Probably you can give an upvote that other guys can see it.

Answer (score 1):

`SQLiteDatabase` is auto-created when first `SQLiteOpenHelper` gets called and you are deleting it `onCreate` with `db.deleteDatabase(new File(DATABASE_NAME));` line. just remove it, (fresh) reinstall app and you db should be created properly and inserting should start work

note that when you will create your table with e.g. only one and further you will add another column then you have to handle this in overidden `onUpdate` method, `onCreate` won't be called again

Comment: Good point of you but @Sajjad was at the right point.

But thanks for the advice with onUpdate :D

Probably you can give an upvote that other guys can see it.